What is this "double free of object" error in Python?
I'm using flask, and when I spam pages (to somewhat simulate regular user traffic), I get this error:
Python(34855,0x70000359d000) malloc: Double free of object 0x7fe091c4b610
Python(34855,0x70000359d000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:254: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '

By the way, I'm using a Macbook, running Ventura 13.7.  Python version is 3.12.5.
The application crashed.
Is this a problem with Flask or Python?

It's nothing about flask.
Double free means the program is going to release a memory block which has been released already, and it will causes error for sure.
I think the problem you met is recorded as issur:82300 on GitHub. The resource tracker of Python currently destroys shared memory segments on posix systems (MacOS included) when any independently created Python process with a handle on a shared memory segment exits.
This issue is reported on version 3.7-3.12 of Python. Although it is still open now, it has been fixed by adding track keyword argument to multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory for 3.13.
When working with a earlier version before 3.13 (3.12.5 you are using for example), you can get your multiprocessing.resource_tracker patched by:
from multiprocessing import resource_tracker
 
def fix_register(name, rtype):
    if rtype == "shared_memory":
        return
    return resource_tracker._resource_tracker.register(self, name, rtype)
 
def fix_unregister(name, rtype):
    if rtype == "shared_memory":
        return
    return resource_tracker._resource_tracker.unregister(self, name, rtype)
 
def patch_ban_shm_tracing():
    resource_tracker.register = fix_register
    resource_tracker.unregister = fix_unregister
    if "shared_memory" in resource_tracker._CLEANUP_FUNCS:
        del resource_tracker._CLEANUP_FUNCS["shared_memory"]

patch_ban_shm_tracing()

Or, the code from tanrbobanr:
import sys
import threading
from multiprocessing import resource_tracker as _mprt
from multiprocessing import shared_memory as _mpshm


if sys.version_info >= (3, 13):
    SharedMemory = _mpshm.SharedMemory
else:
    class SharedMemory(_mpshm.SharedMemory):
        __lock = threading.Lock()

        def __init__(
            self, name: str | None = None, create: bool = False,
            size: int = 0, *, track: bool = True
        ) -> None:
            self._track = track

            # if tracking, normal init will suffice
            if track:
                return super().__init__(name=name, create=create, size=size)

            # lock so that other threads don't attempt to use the
            # register function during this time
            with self.__lock:
                # temporarily disable registration during initialization
                orig_register = _mprt.register
                _mprt.register = self.__tmp_register

                # initialize; ensure original register function is
                # re-instated
                try:
                    super().__init__(name=name, create=create, size=size)
                finally:
                    _mprt.register = orig_register

        @staticmethod
        def __tmp_register(*args, **kwargs) -> None:
            return

        def unlink(self) -> None:
            if _mpshm._USE_POSIX and self._name:
                _mpshm._posixshmem.shm_unlink(self._name)
                if self._track:
                    _mprt.unregister(self._name, "shared_memory")


The error is usually related to manual management of memory.Python connects with an external library performs manual memory management, it may not automatically manage the memory, and in case it doesn't work, the memory is freed up or only once
